# Inequality regarding sum of gaussian on lattices

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, lattices, inequalities, arakelov-theory

When S is a subset of an inner product space, let d(S) denote ${\sum\limits_{s \in S} e^{- \langle s,s \rangle}}$

Suppose L is a discrete additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R^n}$, M is a subgroup of L, and V is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Does this hold in general: ${\frac{d(L)} {d(L \cap V)}} \geq  {\frac{d(M)}{d(M \cap V)}}$?

Why I am interested in this:
There are analogies (analogue of the Riemann Roch theorem for example) which imply it makes sense to think of metrized lattices as sheaves and the log of d as the dimension of the global sections of a sheaf(by "metrized lattice" I mean a lattice with an inner product).
So then given a map between metrized lattices, say f: A -> B, an analogous way to define "rank of induced map on global sections" would be:
log(d(A)) - log(d(ker(f))) (from the rank-nullity theorem). I will denote this quantity as rank(f).
So then if this rank function actually behaves as "rank of induced map on global sections", we would expect that $rank(g \circ f)$ is no greater than either rank(f) or rank(g). I am trying to show this for homomorphisms between metrized lattices that don't increase the norm at any point.
$rank(g \circ f) \leq rank(f)$ is trivial; $rank(g \circ f) \leq rank(g)$ is equivalent to this problem I have posed.

I am interested in this rank function because it seems to be possible to do derived functor cohomology without an actual left-exact functor but with just the
ranks of the maps that a left-exact functor would induce. Fully explaining myself here would result in an unreasonably big MO question.

$\textbf{Update:}$ The ideas mentioned in the previous paragraph, which are what originally motivated me to consider this question, are now fully explained [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.05797). Oded and Noah's result is applied in section 7.

Comment: Interesting question.  I don't remember encountering such an inequality,
and don't readily see a proof or counterexample.
Have you tried some examples with $n=2$ and $n=3$ to see if
it seems to work numerically in all cases?

Comment: Is $V$ an $L$-rational subspace?

Comment: Since you can make dilatations of L, your question is really about evaluations of θ−series $\sum_{\lambda\in L}q^{\langle \lambda,\lambda\rangle}$ of lattices at reals in $(0,1)$. (You get of course equality at q=0, your inequality should thus break down at negative evaluations. And you get divergent quantities for $q\geq 1$.)

Comment: @Noam I have made a python script that randomly generates three vectors in  $\mathbb{R^3}$, call them a, b, and c, and the lattices they generate A, B, and C. It then checks if ${\frac{d(A + B + C)} {d(A + B)}} \geq  {\frac{d(A + C)}{d(A)}}$ . Unless you coincidentally have linear dependence among these vectors, this is going to be a special case of the problem. I have checked several thousand random cases with this script without having found a counterexample. Also, I have proven: when we have two lattices D and E whose intersection is {0}, $\frac{d(D + E)} {d(D)} \geq  d(E)$.

Comment: This can be seen by grouping the sum into pairs d + e and d - e, and then using the fact that x + 1/x is minimized at 1.

Comment: @Asaf I'm not 100% sure what you mean by L-rational subspace. If you mean that the dimension of $L \cap V$ is the same as the dimension of V, then it shouldn't make a difference since replacing V by the span of $L \cap V$ is L-rational by this definition and gives the same quantities in the inequality.

Comment: It might be interesting to consider the special case where the lattice comes from the fractional ideal of a number field. Then you could use the functional equation of the theta function. See http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9802121v3.pdf or http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~rossler/mypage/pdf-files/rossler-diplom.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oded Regev and I just posted a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04796) to the arXiv that answers this question. See Corollary 4.4. In particular, we show that the OP's inequality does in fact hold and that it follows from a new inequality concerning the Gaussian mass of lattice cosets.

Interestingly, we came to this question from a very different perspective; we were trying to improve upon the current fastest known algorithm for the shortest vector problem on lattices.