# Is the heat kernel more spread out with a smaller metric?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-equations, inequalities, heat-equation

Suppose M is a smooth manifold, and we have two Riemannian metrics on M, say g and h, with g bigger than h (i.e. for every tangent vector at every point, the norm according to g is bigger than the norm according to h).
Suppose $H_g$ and $H_h$ are the heat kernels on (M, g) and (M, h) respectively.
Does ${\frac{H_g(x, y, t)} {H_g(x, x, t)} \leq \frac {H_h(x, y, t)}{H_h(x, x, t)}}$ necessarily hold for all x, y, and t?

This intuitively makes sense: if you have something diffusing on M, starting at the point x, it should diffuse "faster" with the metric h because distances are smaller, and so after time t it seems you should have a greater proportion of the diffusing substance at y compared to at x. On $\mathbb{R^n}$ this is trivially true, also I've tested it out numerically for a variety of metrics on the circle and it seems to hold. But a proof eludes me.

While I am curious about the general case, I'm especially interested when the manifolds in question are quotients of $\mathbb{R^n}$ by a lattice, with the corresponding flat metrics, because an affirmative answer in this special case can be used to solve [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160507/inequality-regarding-sum-of-gaussian-on-lattices).

$\textbf{Update:}$ I've found a proof of this for the special case of translation-invariant metrics on the circle. For these spaces, the heat kernel $H(0, x ,t)$, as a function of x, is given by a wrapped Gaussian function. The variance of the Gaussian that gets wrapped is determined by t and the metric, and a smaller metric has larger variance for a fixed t. The problem then boils down to the following assertion:

> If $a$, $b$, and $s$ are real numbers with $0 < a \leq b < 1$, then
>   $$\frac{\sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a^{(n + s)^2}}{\sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a^{n^2}} \leq \frac{\sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} b^{(n + s)^2}}{\sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} b^{n^2}} $$

From the Poisson summation formula, the above is equivalent to:

> If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real numbers with $1 > \alpha \geq \beta > 0$, and $z$ is a complex number of norm 1, then
>   $$\frac{\sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} {\alpha^{n^2} z^{n}}}{\sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \alpha^{n^2}} \leq \frac{\sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} {\beta^{n^2} z^{n}}}{\sum\limits_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \beta^{n^2}} $$

From the Jacobi triple product, the above is equivalent to:

$$\prod\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(1 + \alpha^{2m - 1}z)(1 + \frac{\alpha^{2m - 1}}{z})}{(1 + \alpha^{2m - 1})^2}} \leq \prod\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(1 + \beta^{2m - 1}z)(1 + \frac{\beta^{2m - 1}}{z})}{(1 + \beta^{2m - 1})^2}}$$

It's easy to verify that the expressions inside the infinite products are positive for each m (recall that $|z| = 1$, and so $\frac{1}{z} = \overline{z}$), and so it suffices to show that we have this for each $m \geq 1$:

$$\frac{(1 + \alpha^{2m - 1}z)(1 + \frac{\alpha^{2m - 1}}{z})}{(1 + \alpha^{2m - 1})^2} \leq \frac{(1 + \beta^{2m - 1}z)(1 + \frac{\beta^{2m - 1}}{z})}{(1 + \beta^{2m - 1})^2}$$

For the sake of concision, let $p = \alpha^{2m - 1}$ and $q = \beta^{2m - 1}$.
We are done if we can show the following:

$$\frac{(1 + pz)(1 + \frac{p}{z})}{(1 + p)^2} \leq \frac{(1 + qz)(1 + \frac{q}{z})}{(1 + q)^2}$$

Or equivalently:

$$0 \leq (1 + qz)(1 + \frac{q}{z})(1 + p)^2 - (1 + pz)(1 + \frac{p}{z})(1 + q)^2$$

By expanding and factoring the right side, it can be shown that the above is equivalent to:

$$0 \leq (1 - \Re(z))(p - q)(1 - pq)$$

It's easy to show that each of the three terms in the product is non-negative, and this proves the inequality, and so we are done.

Comment: Are you aware of the asymptotic expansion for the heat kernel in terms of $t:$     $H_t(p,q)= h_t(p,q)(\theta_0(p,q)+t\theta_1(p,q)+...),$   where $h_t(p,q)=\frac{1}{(4 \pi t)^{dim M/2}}exp(-d(p,q)^2/4t)$ and $\theta_0(p,p)=1.$ At least for small $t$ and nearby points $p,q$ this should give your inequality.

Comment: @Sebastian No I wasn't aware, thanks for pointing that out. I see that the $h_t$ functions will satisfy the inequality, but I don't see how that is necessarily preserved after multiplying by the series on the right without more information about these $\theta_n$.

Comment: The only thing I know about the $\theta$'s is that they can be expressed in terms of connection data along the diagonal, see for example the book of John Roe: Elliptic operators,... . But if I remember correctly, the series $(\theta_0(p,q)+t\theta_1(p,q)+...)$ converges for small t and nearby $p,q$ to a smooth map which is the identity for $t=0$ and $p=q.$ Therefore, you can get the inequality in a neighbourhood of the diagonal times the $t=0$ slice.

Comment: The heat operator has the "finite propagation speed" property which allows one to estimate the support of $e^{t\Delta}f$ in terms of the support of $f$.  There are estimates of the propagation speed involving metric data, but I don't know off the top of my head if they are sharp enough to get what you want.

Comment: @Paul Siegel: I am surprised by your assertion. The heat semigroup typically has *in*finite speed of propagation, that is, as soon as the initial data are positive but not identically 0, the solution of the heat equation is instanteneously strictly larger than 0 at any point of the domain/manifold. This can be e.g. proved by irreducibility of the semigroup, see e.g. Ouhabaz' 2005 book. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oded Regev and I just posted a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04796) to the arXiv that shows that this does in fact hold over $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathcal{L}$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is a lattice. See Proposition 4.2.

The general case does not hold. In particular, if the second-largest eigenvalue of the heat kernel is unique, then as $t$ approaches infinity, the point with the highest mass will be the point that maximizes the corresponding eigenfunction. I think Jeff Cheeger originally pointed this out to Oded.